# UISearchBar not getting centered when pinned below a UINavigationBar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, nslayoutconstraint, pure-layout

I have this code below who configures the constraints of the view:

```swift
func configNavigationBarConstraints() {
    navigationBar.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .leading)
    navigationBar.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .trailing)
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        return
    }
    navigationBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

func configSearchBarConstraints() {
    searchBar.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: navigationBar)
    //    taskHistorySearchBar.autoPinEdge(.top, to: .bottom, of: navigationBar, withOffset: 6) //This is a solution but no ideal, the height diff varies by device
    searchBar.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .left)
    searchBar.autoPinEdge(toSuperviewEdge: .right)
}
```

This results into this view:

[image]

Note that the UISearchBar is not aligned, any idea of what I can do? Even if I set it to have a high height value by constraint, the center is offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably set the UINavigationBar's delegate and UISearchBar's delegate, both extends `UIBarPositioningDelegate`, so you need to do this:

```
extension ViewController: UINavigationBarDelegate {
  func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {
    if bar is UINavigationBar {
      return .topAttached
    }
    return .any
  }
}
```

This will only apply the `.topAttached` setting for the `UINavigationBar`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on iOS 15.x. I thought it would from the UIBarPositioning docs. But no.